# Asp.net forms authentication for users in sqlserver

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, forms-authentication

I want to use form authentication in ASP.net . Users are in a database of my project. my codes are below.but these codes doesn't work.(users can't login). users are in "users" table in "news"database. 
My web.config file:

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" name=".asp" path="/" timeout="1"   >
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
     <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="news"
             applicationName="users"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"  />
      </providers>
    </membership>

  </system.web>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="news" connectionString="Data Source=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ava\Desktop\WebSite3\App_Data\news.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <location path="karbar.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

and my codes in default.aspx form for login is:

```
> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>     if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(user.Text, pass.Text))
>     {
>         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Text, true);
>         FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(pass.Text, true);
>     }
>     else
>         user.Text = ":((((((("; }
```

Comment: Do you have a connection string named `news` in your `Web.Config`?

Comment: Right, seems like name="ConnectionString" should be name="news"

Comment: yes, I have .it is in <appSetting> tag

Comment: My users are in users table in news database. does it need to set this table ?

Comment: I change name to "news" . but this doesn't work yet. when I enter user and pass correctly this think I enter wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your configuration file this way:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="ConnectionString"
         applicationName="users"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"  />
  </providers>
</membership>

</system.web>

<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ava\Desktop\WebSite3\App_Data\news.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Update**
I hope you have also problem in your code change it to

```
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(user.Text, pass.Text))
 {
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Text, true);
     FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Text, true);
 }
```

**Update:** Since you're using your own database no need for membership

```
 <configuration>
  <system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" name=".asp" path="/" timeout="1"   >
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
 <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="news" connectionString="Data Source=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ava\Desktop\WebSite3\App_Data\news.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
 <location path="karbar.aspx">
  <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

See remove the `<membership>` tag all together.

then in code behind read the user record from database put the result in datareader

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       //assume you opened the db

 SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandText="select * from users where username=@name and password=@pass";
  cmd.Connection=conn;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name",user.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass",pass.Text);
 SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (dr.HasRows)
 {
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Text, true);
     FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Text, true);
 }
else labelerror.Text="Incorrect name or pass";
}
```

Now use your table name and I'm hopeful you know what to do. Remember you've only one web form secured karbar.aspx.

Comment: I do this. but any user can't login at all

Comment: Is this need any change in database . Must my database to be in a special format for users table?

Comment: Haven't you configured your database to support membership

Comment: My database has a users table that has 2 columns :user and pass. and has one record

Comment: @AvaBahari: Oh, you'vent configured your database to support membership. So use your own authentication. You don't need to use membership then. Too see how let me take you to chat room

Comment: I can't go to chat room. because I have Not enough score

Comment: how change my web.config for this?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. As others mentioned in comments, make sure the connection name is *news*, **not** in  but in `<connectionStrings>` element.
2. Your database should have a series of special talbes+views+SPs of Forms Authentication, by running [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/06/16/usage-of-aspnet-regsql-exe-in-asp-net-4.aspx). These tables are administered internally by ASP.NET's authentication/membership/role providers.

Comment: My database has a users table that has 2 columns :user and pass. and has one record

Comment: is there any other way for me?

Answer (score 0):

In The Following Tag :

```
<forms loginUrl="default.aspx" name=".[CookieName]" path="/" timeout="1" >
```

Put The name of your cookie in the name property .

Also --> change the seconde parameter in :

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(pass.Text, true);
```

to

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(pass.Text, false);
```